# Implement 'import' and 'export' keywords in V8 javascript shell

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8

**note:** I am asking about **Google's V8 engine**, not Joyent's node.js, please do not respond with *require()* or another trivial solution like that

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20from%20Source to build V8 from source.

in the build directory, the *v8_shell* executable works and I can evaluate expressions like 
`print(Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(this)))` because the *v8_shell* example source code implements custom functions/variables: `print,read,load,quit,version`

How would I go about implementing ECMAScript 6 `import` and `export` in this *v8_shell* example? I want variants to work as expected, examples:
`import something from 'module'` or `import 'module'`. For the sake of simplicity lets assume only files in the current working directory are allowed.

Full list of variants of `import/export`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Sounds like you are asking someone to implement (some form of) ES6 module support in V8, which is definitely way too broad.

Comment: @FelixKling maybe?  or maybe it's just not supported in the shell and they just want a pass through of some sort?  I don't actually know anything about v8_shell

Comment: Did you start d8 with --harmony-dynamic-import?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to go through the API (include/v8.h) if you want to access the file system. This shouldn't be possible from within d8.

Comment: FelixKling not asking someone to do it for me rather explain where I can hook into V8 to capture the import/export keyword parsing and do it myself.
@user835611: *Warning: unknown flag --harmony-dynamic-import*. I understand I would need to code the filesystem access part myself, where in V8 can I hook into the parsing and processing of import/export keyword statements?

Comment: d8 has a load function, maybe you can just patch that to work for import. A bunch of JS functions are defined in src/js, you could define your import there to just call load (obviously, not real modules syntax).

Comment: What d8 version did you build? 5.8 candidate has the --harmony-dynamic-import flag.

Comment: It should be supported in d8 already